# Where to find Red Pitaya developer manual

Tags: redpitaya

Does anyone know if Red Pitaya developer manuals are already available since the launch date is approaching, and where to get them?

Any other developer resources already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web page is updated now - as of yesterday. I found the Users Manual, the code developer guide and a short description of FPGA development for Red Pitaya here: http://wiki.redpitaya.com/index.php?title=Main_Page
So far the source code is not uploaded yet.

Answer (score 1):

Red Pitaya claims in their materials (kickstarter campaign, comments and answers) that all the instructions and supporting material would be available at the launch date. It would be nice to get the instructions earlier though. Anyway, as stated, it is only a few days until the launch.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Red Pitaya manuals at http://wiki.redpitaya.com/index.php?title=Main_Page. It looks very nice!